# CSS tr hover excluding tr with certain class

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a table which is populated by some JS on opening and as part of that, section headings are given a column span across the whole table as well as a classname of "section".  I verified this by an alert in the onmouseover hook for the tr elements which echoed the classname.  The classname definitely takes.

I have some CSS like this...

```
tr:hover {
    background-color: #FF9966
}
thead tr:hover, tr.section:hover {background-color: #DACFE5;!important}
```

The roll-over works fine and excludes the thead children, but I cant get it to exclude "section" class tr's.

What syntax do I need in the CSS to achieve this?

The table template is...

```
<table id="myTable" border="1" class="indent">
  <thead>
    <tr> 
      <th colspan="3">Joe's Cafe Menu</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Select</th>
      <th>Item</th>
      <th>Price</th>
    <tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

EDIT:

Problem was case sensitivity.
A rookie error I guess.
classname was being echoed in the alert but the member referenced by the CSS is className.  I fixed that and now its fine.

This CSS works like a charm...

```
tbody tr:not(.section):hover {
    background-color: #FF9966
}
```

For reasons I don't understand, this CSS fails to exclude the header...

```
tr:not(.section):hover {
    background-color: #FF9966
}
thead tr:hover td {background-color: #DACFE5;}
```

Which is academic really since its a bit of a hack.

Comment: Can you show a sample of your table markup that contains `tr.section`s? You can obtain this by viewing the DOM or the generated source after the table is populated.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/8nw6vkej/

Comment: @BoltClock I don't know how to view the HTML after the JS has modified it.  Can you advise?

Comment: One of the easiest way (if you can modify the template that is used by the JS) would be to add a class name (or ID) to the each `td` then use that class to add (or exclude) these. Can you modify the template?

Comment: @morespace54 OK thanks for the advice, yes I can modify it, its only a learning exercise.  I was trying to find a way to avoid that but perhaps the most direct way is best.

Comment: @Oriol If the class is added statically into the HTML then yes, it works fine, the problem I seem to be having is that the class is added, but the CSS is not aware of it.  I tried moving the link element below the script in the head section but still no difference. The code that builds the table runs on the onload event.

Comment: @CoolBlue Can't reproduce it: http://jsfiddle.net/8nw6vkej/12/. Edit: Ah, now I see you were using `classname` instead of `className`.

Comment: Your last code doesn't work with the header because in the selector you have `td`, but in your html you are have `th`.

Answer (score 1):

`tr:not(.section):hover {
    background-color: #FF9966
}`

Comment: Thanks, yes I tried that also but no joy. It's a bit strange because the intelisense in my editor offered .section as an option one time, but then it disappeared. I guess its because it is not there at design time.  The class is inserted after the load event.